# How to achieve required output using Jolt specification - Apache NiFi

Tags: json, apache-nifi, jolt

Input:

```json
[ 
  {
    "ImageId" : [ "ami-06a13556596424b", "ami-04d29b6f966df15" ],
    "InstanceId" : [ "i-0b456d23d0a5e44", "i-072b95b1d6a4b11" ],
    "InstanceType" : [ "t2.micro", "t2.micro" ]
  } 
]
```

required output:

```json
[
  {
    "ImageId": "ami-06a13556594b01",
    "InstanceId": "i-0b456d23d0a5e3",
    "InstanceType": "t2.micro"
  },
  {
    "ImageId": "ami-04d29b6f966df37",
    "InstanceId": "i-072b95b1d6a436",
    "InstanceType": "t2.micro"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the fllowing shift transformation spec :

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": { 
          "*": { // the indexes of the respective arrays
            "@": "[&].&2"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

where

- **&2** copies the keys of the arrays respectively
- **[&]** separates the objects by the indexes of the arrays to return in array-wise maner as a whole

the ***demo*** on the site https://jolt-demo.appspot.com/ is :

[image]